# WinAPI Aero Glass without ATL/WTL/MFC/SDK/etc

Tags: c++, winapi, aero, aero-glass

I've been looking for ages for C++ examples for Aero Glass interfaces using just WinAPI (`CreateWindow`/`CreateWindowEx`) *without* ATL/WTL/MFC/etc.

I found someone linking to one somewhere on a forum but the link was dead and I couldn't find any others.

Any ideas where I can find one?

Comment: I just realized you were asking for examples - not a how-to for getting Aero to work.

Comment: @Mysticial can you please put the link/header/linker in a comment for me please. I would still like to have a read.

Comment: The link was http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773175.aspx

Comment: which aspects of glass are you interested in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The samples on this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb688195%28VS.85%29.aspx) are not specific to any framework (except Windows)

Answer (score 0):

Are these helpful?

DrawThemeTextEx 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773317(v=vs.85).aspx

EnableTheming 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773324(v=vs.85).aspx